# Highcharts not changing x-axis label on pagination

Tags: highcharts, pagination

I have found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/5/) very helpful when I started working on paginated highchart columns. On top of this good example, I would like to know how I could change the x-axis labels into each data's corresponding name. (Ex. Along the x-axis, we should find the names of 'Fred G. Aandahl', 'Watkins Moorman Abbitt', 'Amos Abbott', etc. with their corresponding y-values and must change accordingly when the "Next" button is clicked.)

I have tried adding "xAxis" option inside the highcharts portion but still had no luck.

```
  pie = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function(){
                    return this.value;
                }
             }
        },
        series: [{
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

and

```
pie = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                  format: '{value}'
              }
        },
        series: [{
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

Can someone help me regarding on what I am missing in this example? It will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to change the x-axis labels accordingly by adding

```
pie.xAxis[0].update({
    categories: category.slice(from, to)
})
```

after the setData call, where category is an array of all the x-axis labels that you want to display in correspondence to each y-axis value. Moreover, the

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
}
```

portion, as suggested by @Kacper Madej, works for the specific data format given originally. However, the **pie.xAxis[0].update()** could be used on a more general sense given that you know the array of x-axis labels that you want to use (regardless of the data or series format that you have).

Here is the link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/14/).

Hope this could be of any help, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can set type of xAxis to category and without category array the value in axis will be taken from the point. But you will need to change your setData call to

**pie.series[0].setData( data.slice(from, to), true, true, false );**

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/8/

Comment: Thank you @Kacper ! It works for the example. But what if I have a separate array of categories that I want to put on the x-axis and not use the values from the point? Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/9/) .

Comment: I tried adding a pie.xAxis[0].update() after the setData call. I am getting the right x-axis labels but it repeats 5 times. I don't why. Do you have ideas why this happens and/or how it can be prevented? @Kacper Madej Here it the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpxp4/11/)